# Laravel collection search case insensitive

Tags: php, laravel

I am searching through a collection and I would like to have this search case insensitive or at least change the collections values in lowercase. How can I do that?

```
$value = strtolower($value);
$collection = $collection->where($attribute, $value);
```

$value is lowercase while the content in the collection not, so there are no matches.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You could instead use the `filter()` method with a callback that does what you want:

```php
$collection = $collection->filter(function ($item) use ($attribute, $value) {
    return strtolower($item[$attribute]) == strtolower($value);
});
```

Comment: any differences between filter and where?

Comment: @Stefano Maglione, `where` uses `filter` internally, `filter` uses `foreach`, and yeah I understand that filter gives more power to work on the collection and add more constraints etc

Answer (score 0):

You can map over the collection and lowercase the attribute for each item:

```
$value = strtolower($value);
$collection = $collection
    ->map(function ($item) use ($attribute) {
        $item->{$attribute} = strtolower($item->{$attribute});

        return $item;
    })
    ->where($attribute, $value);
```

Comment: That would transform the collection’s contents though. I think the OP just wants to filter items based on a condition.

Comment: @MartinBean true, your solution is better.

Comment: @StefanoMaglione can you add to your question what $collection, $value and $attribute are?

Answer (score 0):

I created a [Collection Macro](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/collections#extending-collections) for performing a case-insensitive search.

The version I have below will fetch the first item in a collection matching a case-insensitive item.

Add this to your service provider:

```
    Collection::macro('insensitiveFirstWhere', function ($key, $value = null) {
        if (func_num_args() === 1) {
            $value = true;
        }
        else if (is_string($value)) {
            $value = mb_strtolower($value);
        }

        return $this->first(function ($item) use ($key, $value) {
            $itemValue = $item->{$key};
            if (is_string($itemValue)) {
                $itemValue = mb_strtolower($itemValue);
            }
            return $itemValue == $value;
        });
    });
```

To use it, simply call:

```
$collection = collect(['name' => 'John'], ['name' => 'Bobby']);
// will return John, as 'John' == 'john'
$collection->insensitiveFirstWhere('name', 'john');
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplifying and generalizing @zuc0001's answer...

You can add a collection macro to provide a case-insensitive 'where' match by adding this to your AppServiceProvider:

```
\Illuminate\Support\Collection::macro('whereCaseInsensitive', function (string $field, string $search) {
        return $this->filter(function ($item) use ($field, $search) {
            return strtolower($item[$field]) == strtolower($search);
        });
    });
```

Usage example:

```
$collection = collect([['name' => 'John'], ['name' => 'Bobby']]);
$john = $collection->whereCaseInsensitive('john');
// $john is ['name' => 'John']
```