# Laravel Eloquent Collection Where Not Working As Expected

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I am unable to know why filtering the retrieving collection does not provide me the data. Could anybody explain why this particular issue occurred?

```
$products = Product::get();

//$collection is retrive from the excel
foreach($collections as $collection){
   // Scenario 1:
   $product = $products->where('product_name', $collection[0])->first();
   dd($product); // Returns null
   
   // Scenario 2
   $product = Product::where('product_name', $collection[0])->first();
   dd($product); // It provides me the Product Model instance
}
```

Filtering in the collection does not provide me the Model Instance, whereas Querying inside a loop provides me the Model Instance. I want to optimize the query, so I previously retrieve all products.

Information:

*Product Count = 743*

*Product Id found for first loop = 12*

*Collection $collection Count = 1486*

Comment: looks weird, I've checked the same code and it works... Did you check the collection `producsts` contains the element with such a name?

Comment: Yes. The problem was because of case insensitivity. In the Model filter, it does not matter; whereas in the Collection filter, case-sensitivity does affect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was because of collection filter was case sensitive.

*Product Name in Database: 'Testing Product'*

*Excel Value: 'testing product'*

**Collection Filter: null (Case sensitive)**

**Model Filter: $model (Case insensitive)**

If any future SO stumbled upon how to make the collection case-insensitive, I have copied the SO answer on [converting collection filter case-insensitive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44922821/laravel-collection-search-case-insensitive)

```
$collection = $collection->filter(function ($item) use ($attribute, $value) {
    return strtolower($item[$attribute]) == strtolower($value);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code:

```
$names = [];
foreach($collections as $collection){
   $names[] = $collection[0];
}
$products = Product::whereIn('product_name', $names)->get()
```